# choropleth map of malayasia with range slider JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, highcharts, choropleth

I tried with highcharts. But there is no option to have a range slider to change map color.

I need to have a map of malaysia with states color changing according to slider. D3 js have only US states with slider.

```
var data = [
['my-sa', 0],
['my-sk', 1],
['my-la', 2],
['my-pg', 3],
['my-kh', 4],

 ];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
chart: {
    map: 'countries/my/my-all'
},

title: {
    text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/my/my-all.js">Malaysia</a>'
},

mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    }
},

colorAxis: {
    min: 0
},

series: [{
    data: data,
    name: 'Random data',
    states: {
        hover: {
            color: '#BADA55'
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}'
    }
}, {
    name: 'Separators',
    type: 'mapline',
    data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/my/my-all'], 'mapline'),
    color: 'silver',
    showInLegend: false,
    enableMouseTracking: false
}]
```

});

Any thoughts?

Comment: extract the geojson from `my-all.js` and use it in D3 USA choropleth example, or use http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/my/my-all.geo.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to implement range slider with Highmaps. I prepared an example with Malayasia map chart:

```
$('#slider').on('input', function(e) {
    ...
    chart.series[0].setData(data[this.value]);
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rkutdxva/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData